# Suspects and cops

Tags: probability, combinatorics

16 cops and 8 suspects are sitting in a row, waiting for a train.

It would be desirable that each suspect is flanked on both sides by cops.

If they sit randomly, what is the expected value of the # of suspects so flanked ?

Comment: What about extremities? If $C$ is a cop and $S$ is a suspect, do you consider 
$$
SCC \dots CS
$$
the suspects at both ends flanked or not?

Comment: @Patrick: No, they have to be flanked on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expectations add, so you can compute an individual suspect's odds of being flanked and then multiply by 8. Each suspect has a $\frac{22}{24}$ chance of sitting somewhere other than the ends (where said suspect cannot be flanked), and then there is a $\frac{16}{23}$ chance the person to his left will be a cop, and then a $\frac{15}{22}$ chance the person to his right will be a cop (given that the person to his left is a cop).
$$\frac{22}{24}\cdot\frac{16}{23}\cdot\frac{15}{22}=\frac{10}{23}$$
The expected number of suspects flanked by cops is $\frac{80}{23}$

Comment: I'm sorry if this is basic but how do you obtain 16 out of *23*? I tried to repeat the pattern for smaller numbers of cops/suspects in order to understand, yet it didn't work out.